# How do I trigger click event on dynamically created input type 'file'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to add an input of type 'file' to a form dynamically.  Actually the end user can add as many files as they would like to a form, so an array concept is needed.  I can inject dynamic elements, but I can't figure out how to dynamically invoke the click of the input element just injected.  Also, need to remove the dynamic element if the user chooses cancel on the input element.

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keht6ud7/) showing the injection but the click event never fires when the trigger is run.

How do I trigger the 'click' event after injecting this element?

**jsFiddle Html**

```
<input id='button1' type='button' value='button1'>
<div class='container'>

</div>
```

**jsFiddle JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button1').on('click', function(event) {
    Button1_Click(event);
  });
});

function Button1_Click(event) {
    var container = $('.container');
  var containerChildren = $(container).children();
  var containerChildrenCount = $(containerChildren).length;
  var inputId = 'fileInput[' + containerChildrenCount + ']';
    $('.container').append('<input id="' + inputId + '" type="file" />');
  $('#' + inputId).trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `[]` from the inputId variable.

I got it to work in your fiddle by changing it to this

`var inputId = 'fileInput-' + containerChildrenCount`

Comment: This works.  Not sure why the brackets caused a problem - good find.  Any idea how to detect when a user selects cancel in the Open File dialog box?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to detect change in the dialog box. 
I think the original problem came from allowed chars - quite simple but easy to miss :)

Checkout this link: http://xahlee.info/js/html_allowed_chars_in_attribute.html